Criterion for the Lurie tensor product of $\infty$-categories to commute with infinite products
The title of the question says it all. When does the Lurie tensor product of $\infty$-categories ([Higher Algebra] Section 4.8.1) commute with infinite products?
$$\mathcal{C} \otimes \prod_{i\in I}{\mathcal{D}_{i}} \cong \prod_{i \in I} ( \mathcal{C} \otimes\mathcal{D}_i )$$
for $I$ some infinite set.
I think it's very wrong in general (Example: in the setting of $k$-linear stable $\infty$-categories $\operatorname{perf}(k') \otimes_{k} \prod_{i\in \mathbf{Z}}{\operatorname{perf}(k)} \ncong \prod_{i \in \mathbf{Z}}  \operatorname{perf}(k')  $ for $k'/k$ an infinite field extension).
But it should be true if $\mathcal{C}$ is dualizable.
Is this true? Is something weaker than dualizable possible?

I think it should often be the case. Because PrL is fully ambidextrous products and coproducts agree, and the lurie tensor product preserves colimits.

First, a clarification about the question : as Marius points out in the comments, it sort of depends on what you mean by Lurie tensor product. If you mean the one at the level of presentable categories, then indeed this is no condition at all and is always true. But from your example it seems like you mean the one at the level of small stable categories where it starts being a more stringent condition.
As you say, dualizability clearly implies that condition (in any category, it does), and I claim that the converse is true in the context of small stable, $k$-linear $\infty$-categories, that is, if this is true for all products of $D_i$'s, then $C$ is dualizable (of course it may happen that this map is an equivalence for a very specific family of $D_i$'s without $C$ being dualizable)
Recall for this that dualizability in this context is equivalent to smoothness and properness.
Step 1: $C$ is proper. For the canonical map to even be fully faithful, you need that for any $x,y\in C$ and family $d_i,e_i \in D_i$, the map $\operatorname{map}(x,y) \otimes \prod_i \operatorname{map}(d_i,e_i) \to \prod_i \operatorname{map}(x,y)\otimes \operatorname{map}(d_i,e_i)$ is an equivalence. Letting the $D_i$'s be arbitrary shows that $\operatorname{map}(x,y)\otimes -$ commutes with arbitrary products in $\operatorname{Mod}_k$, and hence arbitrary limits. It follows from this that each $\operatorname{map}(x,y)$ is perfect over $k$ (this is a similar exercise but one category level down).
This shows that the example you gave is correct : infinite field extensions do not have that property.
Step 2: $C$ is generated by a single object. This is an easy exercise : if it weren't, take $I$ to be a large set, $D_i= \operatorname{Perf}(k)$ and in $\prod_I C$ take a family of objects that is never generated by a finite subset of $C$ - this cannot lie in the image of the canonical functor.
Corollary of steps 1 & 2 : $C$ is a sequential colimit of compact (stable, $k$-linear) categories.
Step 3: $C$ is smooth. I'll instead prove that $C$ is compact, which implies smoothness (this is due to Toën I think, but is also not super difficult to show these days) - thus after this step we'll be done. The argument for this is similar to step 2, but a bit more involved. It's likely that there is a simpler argument here but I couldn't figure it out.
The key lemma is that for $S$ smooth and $P$ proper, the canonical functor $\operatorname{Fun}^{ex}_k(S,\operatorname{Perf}(k))\otimes P \to \operatorname{Fun}^{ex}_k(S,P)$ is an equivalence. I'll take that for granted for now, though it's not obvious. Feel free to ask about it.
With this lemma and the previous corollary, we can do the following : write $C=\operatorname{colim}_n A_n$ where the $A_n$'s are compact, and look at the map $C\otimes \prod_n \operatorname{Fun}^{ex}_k(A_n, \operatorname{Perf}(k)) \to \prod_n ( C\otimes \operatorname{Fun}^{ex}_k(A_n,\operatorname{Perf}(k))) \to \prod_n \operatorname{Fun}^{ex}_k(A_n,C)$
By assumption, the first map is an equivalence, and by the key lemma (using that the $A_n$'s are compact and hence smooth, and that by Step 1 $C$ is proper), the second one is too, therefore the composite is. Writing $\operatorname{Fun}^{ex}_k(C,C)=\lim_n \operatorname{Fun}^{ex}_k(A_n,C)$ as an equalizer of two terms that look like $\prod_n \operatorname{Fun}^{ex}_k(A_n,C)$, we find that it is an equalizer of two terms of the form $C \otimes \prod_n \operatorname{Fun}^{ex}_k(A_n, \operatorname{Perf}(k))$ and thus, the identity $id_C$ lifts to a finite stage $A_m \otimes \prod_n \operatorname{Fun}^{ex}_k(A_n,\operatorname{Perf}(k))$ for some large $m$. Unwinding what this means, one sees that $C$ is a retract of $A_m$, and thus is compact itself.
